# Vampire the Masquerade Discipline vs Werewolf Fetish

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, werewolf-the-apocalypse

Recently, in a mixed WoD 20th Anniversary game, we came upon an unexpected problem.

**Phoebe's Veil** - a level 3 Fetish, Gnosis 7

vs.

**Vampire Auspex**

While the Veil says, "Neither mundane creatures nor spirits nor technology may sense her in any way except touch."  the argument was made that Vampires are not mundane - and thus Auspex should pierce it.

On the Flip side of the coin, it is the bound spirits who are concealing the werewolf — in this case, a multiple spirits: a Lune, a chameleon and a shadow. Since Vampires cannot see nor interact with spirits via Auspex at all, it should not.

I have searched a bit on the net and tried to find some kinda of errata for the fetish or something that might give the players a understandable and logical conclusion. (I never like saying, "It works or does not because I said so." I try and give reasoning.) Obviously, saying having Auspex 7 (its Gnosis rating) to see though is kinda out of the question, but also having a 3 (level of fetish) does seem to "limit" its power and usefulness. Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: hey dude, look like you have some answers, maybe you can that one of them answers to your question

Answer (score 6):

As unsatisfactory as this answer might be, i'm pretty sure that these cross-system interactions are left to storyteller devices.

While i lack a clear reference ( and i encourage anyone wielding one at the ready to shed more light onto this case ), i'm pretty sure that towards the end of the Demon: The Fallen book this approach is stated. They also talked in one of their Berlin Conferences ( pretty sure it's [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqr2xUOz7Ag) one ) about how they are working on a more inclusive system, but they have yet to have published one **to date**.

The way i interpret this is that these things are up to storyteller choice,
and the only non-blabber response i can give you is choose what best fits your scenario

Comment: Thanks much for the help - guess ill keep on , keeping on

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no rule for a cross-over situation like this.

I'd rule it like this: To spot someone that uses a fetish to hide you need Auspex at least at the same level as the fetish and then you make and opposed roll like you would to sport someone with Auspex vs obfuscate but the enemy uses the fetishes gnosis value. Thus, it comes down to the roll. Both parties stand a chance and can calculate with it to make their decision.

I’d communicate that rule clearly to the players when they ask and then give them enough time to decide how their character takes the chances he has.

Comment: Thanks much for the information , this seems like a pretty good idea,

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know, Auspex say that a discipline-like power (ex: werewolf fetish) are treathen like a vampire discipline of the same level. So the vampire can see the werewolf if he has Auspex 3 or more (sorry, english is not my natural language).

Comment: Do you have a page reference or quote?

Comment: @T.J.L. I have it in french, it's page 142, in the "voir l'invisible" section (something like "see the unseen" in english)